# Use Office Online Server to provide document editing from within a web application

Tags: ms-office, ms-wopi, office-online-server

We'd like our clients to be able to, from our software, open documents and collaborate on them in the course approving them, then releasing them. We'd like to provide that using Office Online Server from a window within our software (using WOPI protocol). So if I understand correctly, we'd need our software to be able to specify the document, open it in the Office Online Server window/iframe and allow the collaboration to take place there. Then the client would save the document, and our software would take over from there.  Can something like this be done?
From my research, @rocky (user:1332034) is the person that seems most likely to be able to answer these questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is exactly what the WOPI protocol can do for you. The architecture, in your case, should look something like this:

[image: WOPI app architecture]

The [`WopiHost.Discovery`](https://github.com/petrsvihlik/WopiHost/tree/master/WopiHost.Discovery) and [`WopiHost.Url`](https://github.com/petrsvihlik/WopiHost/tree/master/WopiHost.Url) can help you with generating the URLs. [`WopiHost.Core`](https://github.com/petrsvihlik/WopiHost/tree/master/WopiHost.Core) can help with the WOPI protocol communication.

[Diagram link](https://excalidraw.com/#json=HCA7eezqHeeDI51tLEfK0,z57zayVuJCNleHviuO5ecA)

Comment: in this example of using the WOPI protocol in an example similar to the above, would it be possible to interact with the document in the iframe using an Office API or some similar method? Trying to determine if our application can provide tools that help automate content creation within a Word document by interacting with selected text and things like that.

Comment: You use Office.js to extend the office apps (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/quickstarts/word-quickstart?tabs=yeomangenerator). However, it seems the API doesn't play well with custom WOPI endpoints (https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-js/issues?q=is%3Aissue+is%3Aopen+insertOoxml+wopi)